# MySQL Foreign Key Constraint Multiple Tables Same Field

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a comments system where a user can comment on various different types of pages. Each page type (e.g. reviews) has it's own table with an `id` column. In my comments table I have `page_type` and `page_id` which reference the type of page and the `id` column of its respective table.

I would like to have foreign key constraints on the `page_id` column depending on `page_type`, so that if the page ID changes or the page gets deleted the comment will get updated. I know this isn't possible on a single column, but what would be the best solution to this?

I could have a column for each page type that would reference the ID in a specific table and put foreign key constraints on that, but this could get messy as the number of page types begins to grow (currently there are 4).

Comment: The answer depends on the structure of the various "pages" tables. Do they all have the same structure? BTW you're definitely correct that a column for each page type is not the answer; it will get messy.

Comment: @EdGibbs The only thing they have in common is the id column.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support foreign key references on derived columns (there are no derived columns).

So, I would say that if you need a foreign key references to something, then that "something" is an entity.  And that should be where the reference is.  Consider a structure like this:

```
create table pages (
    PageId int not null autoincrement primary key,
    <additional columns common to all pages>
);
```

Then each specific page type can be:

```
create table PagesType1 (
    PageType1Id int not null autoincrement primary key,
    PageId int not null,
    foreign key PageId references pages(PageId)
)
```

This isn't perfect, because two different page types could refer back to the same page.  But, without triggers, this is pretty good for MySQL.  Another solution is to do:

```
create table pages (
    PageId int not null autoincrement primary key,
    <additional columns common to all pages>,
    PageType1Id int unique,
    PageType2Id int unique,
    . . .
    foreign key (PageType1Id) references PagesType1(PageType1Id),
    . . .
);
```

This gets the foreign key relationships correctly.  However, you need a trigger to guarantee than only one value is set.

In any case, the gist of this answer is that you need a `Pages` entity in your database.  There are multiple ways to implement it.